# Assign component properties from dict or other variable in Plotly Dash

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

In Plotly Dash, you construct a dashboard using HTML or HTML-like components. Now there are many more parameters that can be assigned to "Core" or HTML components, many of which may be commonly shared among components. What I'm trying to figure out is how to store common parameters in a data structure, and deploy that to a variety of components. This would either before cleaning up and streamlining verbose parameters into a short and tidy variable name, or tie parameters to one commonly set point for easier modification. An example:

You can change the persistence of data on refresh or browser close with `persistence = True, persistence_type ='memory'` in the component declaration. Expanding the snippet above:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Checklist(
        ['New York City', 'Montréal', 'San Francisco'],
        ['Montréal', 'San Francisco'],
        inline=True,
        persistence = True,
        persistence_type = 'memory'
    )
    dcc.Checklist(
        ['Steakhouse', 'Seafood', 'Italian'],
        ['Steakhouse'],
        inline=True,
        persistence = True,
        persistence_type = 'memory'
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

What I would like to do is store these parameters as a data structure and assign them to the component dynamically.

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html

persist = {'persistence':True, 'persistenceType':'memory'}

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Checklist(
        ['New York City', 'Montréal', 'San Francisco'],
        ['Montréal', 'San Francisco'],
        inline=True,
        persist
    )
    dcc.Checklist(
        ['Steakhouse', 'Seafood', 'Italian'],
        ['Steakhouse'],
        inline=True,
        persist
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

For this specific example, I know I can have the values `True` and `memory` set in a variable, and using that var in the parameter value, but this is just one example and I have some more verbose and challenging situations where I would like to have both the parameter and parameter value stored in a data structure. Is there any way I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `**kwargs` syntax to expand/unpack keyword arguments given a dictionary of parameters, for example :

```py
persist = {'persistence': True, 'persistence_type': 'memory'}

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Checklist(
        ['New York City', 'Montréal', 'San Francisco'],
        ['Montréal', 'San Francisco'],
        inline=True,
        **persist
    )
    dcc.Checklist(
        ['Steakhouse', 'Seafood', 'Italian'],
        ['Steakhouse'],
        inline=True,
        **persist
    )
])
```

@see [Unpacking With the Asterisk Operators](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/#unpacking-with-the-asterisk-operators)

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten about the unpacking operator, as I've never had the opportunity to logically use it. Actually kind of excited to!